# divide timeline graph into 4 line time wise

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, timeline.js

I'm using google timeline graph to make a timeline graph for display one-day full activity.
but when I render the graph it is too congested.
so I have to try to divide the graph into 4 sets,

1. displays 00-00-00 time to 05-59-59
2. displays 06-00-00 time to 11-59-59
3. displays 12-00-00 time to 17-59-59
4. displays 18-00-00 time to 23-59-59
   this is one timeline graph with one label(date) has 4 rows as I mentioned above
   Does anyone can help me with this.
   thank you

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? Some code snippet you tried.

Comment: sure 
https://jsfiddle.net/trkqz1uv/12/
here demo fiddle 
I have to display each name in a separate line

Comment: I tried using setting max-min values in options for the time but I don't get the output

Comment: set [config option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options): `timeline: {groupByRowLabel: false}`

Comment: thanks for your response.
I have to set a group of activities in all rows.
like, activities are performed between 00 AM-6 AM all are in the first row, and so on
when I set 'groupByRowLabel" it will separate all the activities row-wise and also it will give space according to time in the timeline.
I have to set the second row start time to 6 AM
eg. second line Time start with 6 AM
can please suggest something to solve this problem 
thank you

Comment: use multiple charts, you won't be able to have multiple timelines in one chart...